# Which is better, bind after refresh or live() (jQuery)?

Tags: bind, jquery

I update a container with AJAX. Which one is better in terms of performance? Pseudo-code:

```
$.post('get_something.php',function(data){
    $('#container').html(data).find('a').bind('click',function(){
        console.log('Doh!');
    });
});
```

Or this?

```
$('#container a').live('click',function(){
    console.log('Doh!');
});

$.post('get_something.php',function(data){
    $('#container').html(data);
});
```

Comment: The second in combination with `on()`. It is recommended and better in performance to use `on()` instead of `bind()` and `live()` from jQuery 1.7 - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Is `bind()` prefered, if there is a controlled amount, let's say 1-5, of elements that do not update? Then the event would be triggered without wandering around the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I wouldn't recommend using `live` at all (and the jQuery team have deprecated it). I'd use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) (or the new version of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)) with a more targeted container (in your case, `#container`) than the document as a whole.

If you do that, performance at click-time will be so close to the same as to make no difference (we're dealing with a user-generated event here, the odd extra couple of milliseconds makes no never mind).

There are other considerations to (um) consider, though. Suppose we have this markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <a>A link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this code:

```
$("#container").delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    // Do something with the click
    console.log("Link was clicked");
});
$("#wrapper").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Since the `a` is the deepest element, you'd expect a click on the `a` to be handled by the first handler and to see the `console.log` entry. But you won't, because the click isn't actually handled until it reaches the container — and in this case, it won't reach the container because the wrapper element in-between them stops the event.

It's not a negative (I find `delegate` hugely useful and use it all the time), it's just something to consider when you're designing how you handle things.

Comment: What about when there's only 1 element? Is `bind()` bad even then?

Comment: @MarttiLaine: I don't think I said `bind` was bad at all. :-) My point was that either approach is perfectly fine, and you're unlikely to see any real difference in response time on a click. So either use `bind` in the callback, or use `delegate` (or the delegation feature of `on`), whichever you prefer, even with just one element.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two, the first option. However, better than both of them is `delegate()`

```
$("#container").delegate(".filter", "click", function() {
    // do something on click of .filter element.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[FYI](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) it states

"After all, bind seems so much clearer and more direct, doesn’t it? Well, there are 2 reasons we prefer delegate or live to bind:

- To attach handlers to DOM elements that may not yet exist in the DOM.
  Because bind directly binds handlers to the individual elements, it
  cannot bind them to elements that aren’t on the page yet. If you were
  to run $('a').bind(...), and then new links were added to the page
  via AJAX, your bind handler would not work for these. live and
  delegate on the other hand are bound to another ancestor node, so it
  will work for any element exists now or in the future within that
  ancestor element.
- Or to attach a handler to a single element or small group of
  elements, listening for events on descendent elements, instead of
  looping through and attaching the same function to 100 individual
  elements in the DOM. This would be the performance benefit of
  attaching a handler to one (or a small group of) ancestor element(s)
  instead of directly attaching handlers to all elements on the page. "

[answer source](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/)